# PrintWriter needs sleep to work in a loop

Tags: java, android

I have a simple TCP/IP Client in my app, it writes data to the socket using a `PrintWriter` and when i manually send messages via the GUI it works fines, but when i loop it dose not worke.

Does A PrintWriter interrupt it self when called to fast?

```
   out.println(message);
   out.flush();
```

Edit: Somehow how the flushing did not happen fast enough so the client was sending concatenate/multiple string to the Server and the server could not handle it.

Comment: You're missing the rest of your code and a minimal test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a proper SSCCE, it is difficult to know what is really going on here.  But I suspect that the root cause of the delays is in the TCP/IP stack and/or your "network".

Your aggressive flushing of every message *could* result in the TCP stack sending lots of small network packets.  That could lead to temporary network congestion and packet loss.

If that is the problem (and as I said ... we can't tell!) then two options that might help are:

- Flushing less frequently; e.g. once every 0.25 seconds.
- Tuning your platform's TCP/IP stack ... though this probably can't be done in a normal app.

---

> Does `sendMessage` interrupt it self when called to fast?

Nope.

> i need to put in a sleep for 500msec to get it send all the messages.

That's most likely incorrect / inaccurate too, but without seeing your actual code, it is not possible to explain what is actually happening.

Comment: The code is to big to post here, but i think you answered my questing.
Caus the code is fluting without errors. And if the PrintWriter flush can't interrupt it self, it must be network or server side error, So thank for the info. I posted the tcp code anyway. It is just wrappet in a asynTask.